# Press any key to continue: no response

Tags: gunz-the-second-duel

I have this client working on Steam. When I enter, I always come to the same splash with the fading "Press any key to continue"

The game also has its orange sign:

> Server is full, Please try again later.

But I assume that in any moment someone gets out of the game, and when that happens, the sign dissaperars momentarily, the momment where the game should let me in.

I press furiously the keyboard (meaning that nothing works) and game doesn't do anything. I can access to the options though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening is that the game in question's servers are at full capacity.  It's most likely prioritizing players that have been waiting longer than you, meaning that when you try to join, the active slot that you were queuing for was just filled.  This could lead to an error on your end, your client trying to insert you into a slot that has already been filled.  In that case, just restart your game.

My suggestion is to just keep trying.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot control that.  I cannot help something if it is not on the client end.  I gave the best advice I had.  Feel free not to vote.